# Full Channel Name with space prevents channel from displaying

Tags: channel

If I remove the space the channel works,

I have a channel with the a name containing spaces, and it wont show on the site, if I remove the space the channel works fine

Comment: All channels should use the tag `channel_short_name` to stop spaces borking.

Comment: Exactly - "channel name" is used for the label, "channel_short_name" is used in the link.